# Why does getchar() return -1?

Tags: c

In the following code, why are the values of `ch2` and `ch3` equal to `-1`?

```
char ch1;
char ch2;
char ch3;
printf("put Type: ");
ch1 = getchar();
_flushall();
printf("put Type: ");
ch2 = getchar();
_flushall();
printf("put Type: ");
ch3 = getchar();
printf("\n");
printf("the ascii value for this three types is: %d, %d, %d", ch1, ch2, ch3);
```

Comment: But I print the ascii value of their.

Comment: This thing happens when I import external input via cmd

Comment: Your code works fine on my system.

Comment: Where does `_flushall()` come from? This isn't Standard C.

Comment: @alk http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xk9ehd.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) encounters an error, it returns `EOF` (which is a macro that expands into an `int` with a negative value, typically "-1"). This explains why you see the `-1`.

As to *why* `getchar` fails, this is a separate question. Usually it means that it has reached the end of the input stream. I assume this has something to do with the fact that you're flushing it with `_flushall`?